# Android File Manager Library

Tags: android, api, file-manager

I am admittedly not experienced in developing for android. I am looking for some API that lets me browse the users files, without installing a separate app via intents. Right now I have found the `OI File Manager`, but that uses intents to get it's work done. Is there another file manager library available for me to use? Preferably one that is easy to set-up and use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a late answer but I worked on creating an android file explorer recently. https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore

Its really straightforward. Essentially its just 1 file that you would need to integrate into your application - doesn't use intents either.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create your own filebrowser using [this example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html)?

Comment: If you read the OP, I explain why I don't want to.

Comment: I understand that you are looking for a library that doesn't use intents, but I think you have to accept there aren't any publicly available. So I was just pointing you to the best next thing. It's not very difficult to create a library yourself from this example (or to call an existing library via intents for that matter).

Comment: I have ditched the project, and won't be developing for android because of this and some other limitations. But I will accept your answer, so people don't keep answering it.

Answer (score 2):

OpenIntent's FileManager is in fact open source:

https://github.com/openintents/filemanager

It is licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0.

You can integrate its source code in your application.