# How to add a file manager to my app

Tags: java, android, file, file-manager

I am making a quizmaker app and I have finally made it possible to save the quiz. Now I am trying to work on opening the file but I haven't been able to find any information about managing the saved files. I need a small file manager that shows the files in the /data/data/mypackage/files folders, preferably in a user friendly interface.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612812/android-file-manager-library ?

Comment: @harpun I did not, actually. I am going to go over the suggestions in that post

Comment: Marking duplicate, also check OpenIntent's code (new answer to the post).